# accessing properties from blocks, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, queue, block

Hi I am trying to use queues and blocks to Multithread but I am having troubles accessing properties from these blocks. When I use NSLog to print the value of self.photoArray I get null. Can someone explain what I did wrong?  I have tried This

```
 dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickrDownload", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{                                 

        NSArray* photos = [FlickrPhotoSort sortTopPlaces];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.photoArray = photos; });


    });

    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

and this which doesnt use main queue.

```
 dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickrDownload", NULL);

dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{                                 

    NSArray* photos = [FlickrPhotoSort sortTopPlaces];

        self.photoArray = photos; 

});

dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

Here is the setter of photoArray

```
-(void) setPhotoArray:(NSArray *)photoArray{
    if(!_photoArray) _photoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:photoArray];
else 
    _photoArray = photoArray;

}
```

I am following the online stanford courses and the teacher simply called the property like this and it seems to work

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSArray *photos = [FlickrFetcher recentGeoreferencedPhotos];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sender;
            self.photos = photos;
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

Comment: Where's the log statement? What are you doing before it in which order? Are you using ARC?

Comment: I don't know what is ARC, but I am in a tableViewController and I call this code in the ViewDidLoad Method, I call the log statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath Method of the TableViewController

Answer (score 1):

> When I use NSLog to print the value of self.photoArray I get null.

The asynchronously running `[FlickrPhotoSort sortTopPlaces]` is probably still running when you hit the log statement and the property just hasn't been set, yet.

Comment: The problem is that I then use PhotoArray to populate my TableViewController but since self.photoArray is null the cells do not get properly populated. I thought that the controller would have to wait until it has everything it requires?

Comment: No Nik is right, you need a call back from your block to populate your tableview when its done.

Comment: @TerrelGibson Yes of course it has to wait for the data to populate the table view. When the data comes in, just call `reloadData`.

Comment: I put [self.tableView reloadData] in the setter for self.photoArray but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Okay I got it to work, turns out I did have to reload my data but it wasnt working at first because I implemented blocks such as __block NSArray *bPhotoArray = self.bPhotoArray; and for some reason it would not reload the data

Comment: Do u know why the __Block would interfere with reload data?

Comment: You didnt change any meaningful code, so whatever you did, you should probably give somebody some credit.  And if I knew this was for school I would never have bothered.  Learn to code dude.

Answer (score -1):

Since properties invoke a method call I have had no issue setting them within a block.  __block only adds visibility to a variable outside the scope of the block - so that changes to a variable from within the block are seen outside the block's scope.  It has no effect on properties only on using vars directly in the block (where they be ivars or not.)  properties are not ivars they are explicit method calls to a class which sets an ivar outside the scope of the block.

You *should* be retaining the photo array in the setter though - the array will be released at the end of the block otherwise.  I have tons of code setting properties from within blocks with no issues.

Comment: how do I retain the photo array in the setter?

Comment: else 
    _photoArray = [photoArray retain];

}

Answer (score -2):

Use the keyword `__block` for iVars in blocks. This makes sure, that the property stays in memory. If you use ARC and pre 5.0 use `__unsafe_unretained` else `__weak`

```
__block NSArray *bPhotoArray = self.bPhotoArray;
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{                                 

    NSArray* photos = [FlickrPhotoSort sortTopPlaces];
        bPhotoArray = photos; 
});
```

Comment: why cant I just call my property ?

Comment: blocks are copied in the memory. Imagine self is dealloced while you download the images. Than you block code is called with self. This results in a crash. Therefor a block retains self. Calling self in a block results in a cyclic retain -> a leak.

Comment: How come when I tried to do the code that you posted above I keep getting null?

Comment: You are confused about the usage of `__block`.

Comment: You realize that __block will only apply if bPhotoArray is used directly in the block, its not even the same instance as the property which will be set inside the block.

Comment: I understand __block and how they can be used to read/write variables in blocks. Turns out __block was preventing the "reloadData" call somehow. When I removed the block it worked